# React multi-level Slide menu causing error

Tags: reactjs

I'm create a mobile slider menu with React that has multiple levels.

I have a working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-dijkstra-f82v4x?file=/src/menu.js, however once i click the next button on any of the Level 2 items, i get an error that i'm not really able to figure out why it's happening.

Comment: Because you are searching the top-level nodes, not the node for the current menu-submenu.

Comment: i've update the code a bit, but I think i'm still stuck on Menu Level 3, and trying to properly set the Previous Menu and Active Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a recursive search for nested menus.

I created a `rootMenu` that contains the root nodes from the JSON data. This is where the search starts. I stored the title as a state, and used this title to memoize the menu object.

I fixed the back navigation by removing the previous state. This was achieved by populating the parent menu fields for every menu node.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import MobileMenuContainer from "./menu.style";
import mobileMenu from "./constant";
import { GridRow } from "emotion-flex-grid";

const linkParentMenus = (menus, title = null) => {
  if (menus?.length) {
    for (let menu of menus) {
      menu.parentMenu = title;
      linkParentMenus(menu.subMenu, menu.title);
    }
  }
};

const createRootMenu = (menus) => {
  const menu = {
    title: "main",
    subMenu: menus,
    parentMenu: null
  };
  linkParentMenus([menu]);
  return menu;
};

const findSubmenu = (menu, title) => {
  if (menu?.title === title) {
    return menu;
  }
  if (menu?.subMenu?.length) {
    for (let subMenu of menu.subMenu) {
      let found = findSubmenu(subMenu, title);
      if (found != null) {
        return found;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const rootMenu = createRootMenu(mobileMenu);

const MobileMenu = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [activeMenuTitle, setActiveMenuTitle] = useState("main");

  const activeMenu = useMemo(() => {
    return findSubmenu(rootMenu, activeMenuTitle) ?? rootMenu;
  }, [activeMenuTitle]);

  return (
    <MobileMenuContainer {...props}>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav" style={{ display: `none` }} />
      <label htmlFor="nav" className="nav-open">
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
      </label>

      <div className="nav-container level-1">
        <div>{activeMenuTitle}</div>
        <ul>
          {activeMenu.subMenu.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <li key={i}>
                <a href={item.link}>{item.title}</a>

                {item.subMenu && (
                  <div
                    style={{ border: `2px solid red` }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setActiveMenuTitle(item.title);
                    }}
                  >
                    Next
                  </div>
                )}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div className={`level-2 ${activeMenuTitle !== "main" ? "active" : ""}`}>
        <div>{activeMenuTitle}</div>
        <GridRow className="menu-back" align="center">
          <p
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenuTitle(activeMenu.parentMenu ?? "main");
            }}
          >
            Back
          </p>
        </GridRow>

        <ul>
          {setActiveMenuTitle !== "main" &&
            activeMenu.subMenu.map((menu, i) => {
              return (
                <li key={i}>
                  <a href={menu.link}>{menu.title}</a>
                  {menu.subMenu && (
                    <div
                      style={{ border: `2px solid red` }}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setActiveMenuTitle(menu.title);
                      }}
                    >
                      Next
                    </div>
                  )}
                </li>
              );
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </MobileMenuContainer>
  );
};

export default MobileMenu;
```

There is a lot or repeated code above. You can either make a submenu component to keep your transitions), or just render one menu at a time; as seen below.

### A single-view menu

Here is a modified version that only renders one menu at a time:

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import MobileMenuContainer from "./menu.style";
import mobileMenu from "./constant";
import { GridRow } from "emotion-flex-grid";

const linkParentMenus = (menus, title = null) => {
  if (menus?.length) {
    for (let menu of menus) {
      menu.parentMenu = title;
      linkParentMenus(menu.subMenu, menu.title);
    }
  }
};

const createRootMenu = (menus) => {
  const menu = {
    title: "main",
    subMenu: menus,
    parentMenu: null
  };
  linkParentMenus([menu]);
  return menu;
};

const findSubmenu = (menu, title) => {
  if (menu?.title === title) {
    return menu;
  }
  if (menu?.subMenu?.length) {
    for (let subMenu of menu.subMenu) {
      let found = findSubmenu(subMenu, title);
      if (found != null) {
        return found;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const rootMenu = createRootMenu(mobileMenu);

const MobileMenu = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [activeMenuTitle, setActiveMenuTitle] = useState("main");

  const activeMenu = useMemo(() => {
    return findSubmenu(rootMenu, activeMenuTitle) ?? rootMenu;
  }, [activeMenuTitle]);

  return (
    <MobileMenuContainer {...props}>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav" style={{ display: `none` }} />
      <label htmlFor="nav" className="nav-open">
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
      </label>

      <div className="nav-container">
        <div>{activeMenuTitle}</div>
        {activeMenu.parentMenu != null && (
          <GridRow className="menu-back" align="center">
            <p
              onClick={() => {
                setActiveMenuTitle(activeMenu.parentMenu ?? "main");
              }}
            >
              Back
            </p>
          </GridRow>
        )}
        <ul>
          {activeMenu.subMenu.map((menu, i) => {
            return (
              <li key={menu.title}>
                <a href={menu.link}>{menu.title}</a>
                {menu.subMenu && (
                  <div
                    style={{ border: `2px solid red` }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setActiveMenuTitle(menu.title);
                    }}
                  >
                    Next
                  </div>
                )}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </MobileMenuContainer>
  );
};

export default MobileMenu;
```

I also modified the style by removing the various levels. I know you were doing this to show a transition from one menu to the other, but it was too noisy.

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const MobileMenuContainer = styled.div`
  .menu-back {
    gap: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    p {
      color: blue;
    }
  }

  #nav {
    &:checked {
      & + .nav-open {
        transform: rotate(45deg);

        i {
          &:nth-of-type(1) {
            transform: translateY(6px) rotate(135deg);
          }

          &:nth-of-type(2) {
            opacity: 0;
          }

          &:nth-of-type(3) {
            transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(45deg);
          }
        }
      }

      & ~ .nav-container {
        z-index: 9990;
        transform: translateX(0);

        ul li a {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
      }

      & ~ .level-2.active {
        z-index: 10000;
        transform: translateX(0);

        ul li a {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .nav-open {
    z-index: 10000;
    cursor: pointer;

    i {
      display: block;
      width: 24px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      border-radius: 9999px;
      transition: transform 0.2s ease;

      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        margin-top: 4px;
        opacity: 1;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        margin-top: 4px;
      }
    }
  }

  .nav-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 80px;
    height: calc(100vh - 133px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: pink;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
    padding: 24px;

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;

      > li {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        gap: 12px;
        padding: 6px 0;

        a {
          color: blue;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-weight: 500;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default MobileMenuContainer;
```